# MySQL delete query is not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

I am running a query directly in MySQL Workbench. It is a work in progress, but I can't get past this issue.

The query is as follows:

```
#Temporary table to hold dcsIds that are past grace period
CREATE TABLE pastGracePeriod (
    dcsId varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO pastGracePeriod
SELECT dcsId FROM loyaltyOptOutGracePeriod
WHERE optOutDate <= ADDDATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -15 DAY);

#temporary table to hold dcsIds that are validated against subscriptions table
CREATE TABLE validatedDcsIds (
    dcsId varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO validatedDcsIds
SELECT subscriptions.dcsId 
FROM subscriptions
INNER JOIN pastGracePeriod ON subscriptions.dcsId = pastGracePeriod.dcsId
WHERE subscriptions.optOutDate <= ADDDATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -15 DAY)
    AND subscriptions.subscriptionId IN (24,25,30)
    AND subscriptions.optInStatus='N';

#delete items in validatedDcsIds table from externalId table
DELETE FROM externalId
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT dcsId FROM validatedDcsIds
    WHERE externalId.dcsId = validatedDcsIds.dcsId);

DROP TABLE pastGracePeriod;
DROP TABLE validatedDcsIds;
```

The query takes `dcsIds` (PK) from a table called `loyaltyOptOutGracePeriod`, validates them against another table called `subscriptions`, then takes those validated `dcsIds` and deletes them from a table called `externalId`.

The query works fine until it gets to the `DELETE` clause. In the `externalId` table, the PK is a composite key consisting of fields `dcsId`, `appId`, and `appName`. As it is written above, I get `Error 1175: You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column`.

If I change it to:

```
DELETE FROM externalId
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT dcsId FROM validatedDcsIds
    WHERE externalId_backup.dcsId = validatedDcsIds.dcsId)
AND appId <> NULL;
```

I get no errors, but nothing gets deleted from the `externalId` table as expected.

I am at a loss, any suggestions are very welcome!

NOTE: I do not need to know how to disable safe update mode.

Comment: *I get no errors* I don't believe you. None table in your DELETE query contains `appId` column, hence its execution must produce "unknown column" error.

Comment: @Akina appId is a column in the externalId table as part of the composite key. I do not get an error when I run it with that constraint. Why would I lie?

Comment: Unfortunately not enough info, see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9686b8b0db31aff6dd8312a00f0adc1f)

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO which allows to reproduce your issue (or create online fiddle).

Comment: *`AND appId <> NULL`* - this is not correct. Either use IS NOT NULL or null-safe compare operator.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use WHERE EXISTS. Use [Multiple-Table Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html):

```sql
DELETE table1
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON {joining conditions}
WHERE {additional conditions}
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work, either. Again I get no error, but the rows are not being deleted from externalId table.

Comment: Why is multiple-table syntax better here?

Comment: @AndyLester It is more clear. It may avoid some problems (not in current case).